# Throw custom Exception in Custom Attribute in WCF

Tags: wcf, attributes

I have a WCF service and want to put restriction on one of its operations(I want special operation can be called only after 18:00 PM). I declare custom attribute, now I want to throw Custom Exception when time is over(according to my business) but I don't know how to throw it.

```
    [MyAttribute]
    public long InsertOffer(Offer offer)
    {}
```

//*******************************************

```
public class MyAttribute: Attribute, IOperationBehavior
    {

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        return;
    }
    //**********************************

public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
        }
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        
        if (DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().CompareTo(endTime.ToLongTimeString()) > 0)
        {
            throw new EMTException("MY MESSAGE");
        }
    }
}
```

In this case when I want to update service in my client it throws Exception(when I want to update not at run-time).

thanks for your helps

Comment: Do you mean that if the service reference  is updated before 18:00 every day, an exception will be reported?

Comment: No, I mean if the user call the service in wrong time it should throw an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my demo:

We can use IDispatchMessageInspector to intercept all requests and then judge and throw exceptions:

```
public class ServerMessageLogger : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().CompareTo(endTime.ToLongTimeString()) > 0)
        {
            throw new FaultException("MY MESSAGE");
        }
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
       
    }
}
```

Add ServerMessageLogger to the service behavior:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustContractBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public Type TargetContract => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageLogger());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

[image]

Finally, we apply this Attribute to the service. **It should be noted that because we apply this Attribute to the entire service, all methods in the service are subject to this limitation. The solution is to split InsertOffer into another service and then apply it.**

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, I just changed this part:
public Type TargetContract => typeof(IService1);

Comment: And one Question, Is there any way that helps me applying this attribute to the special Operation(instead of Service)?